# Thread exiting with uncaught exception, no errors

Tags: android, multithreading

I've been trying to implement in-app purchases to my app, but for some reason the app exits to homescreen everytime I try to start my test purchase.

```
08-04 18:01:00.659: W/dalvikvm(10597): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fd32a0)
08-04 18:01:00.659: D/AndroidRuntime(10597): Shutting down VM
08-04 18:01:00.659: W/dalvikvm(10597): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fd32a0)
```

This is my logcat, I do not get an error, so I don't know what I did wrong here..

Here's the .java that probably causes the error:

```
package com.mitonanetherlands.buttonchooser;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;
import com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView;

public class BuyPremium extends Activity {

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
            // width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
            // guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
            int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    MoPubView ad1;
    SharedPreferences completedLevels;
    Bundle querySku = new Bundle();
    Bundle skuDetails;
    String sku;
    String price;
    Bundle buyIntentBundle;
    IInAppBillingService mService;
    ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buypremium);

        ImageView thankyou = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thankyou);
        thankyou.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.thank_you, 450, 600));
        ad1 = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adviewpremium);
        ad1.setAdUnitId("d95782d0c22011e295fa123138070049");
        ad1.loadAd();
        bindService(new Intent(
                "com.android.vending.bulling.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
                mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        Button backtomain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BackToMenu);
        backtomain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(
                        "com.mitonanetherlands.buttonchooser.MAINMENU"));
            }
        });

        Button BuyPremium = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BuyButton);
        BuyPremium.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
                skuList.add("pemiumUpgrade");

                querySku.putStringArrayList("premium_apartment_life", skuList);
                Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,
                                    getPackageName(), "inapp", querySku);
                        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                myThread.start();
                int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                if (response == 0) {
                   ArrayList<String> responseList 
                      = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                   for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                      JSONObject object = null;
                    try {
                        object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                      try {
                        String sku = object.getString("productId");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                      try {
                        String price = object.getString("price");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                   }
                }
                try {
                    Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku, "inapp","Premium is aangekocht!");
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                try {
                    startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0),Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ad1.destroy();
        if (mServiceConn != null) {
            unbindService(mServiceConn);
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
       if (requestCode == 1001) {     
        int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
          String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
          String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString("productId");
                Toast.makeText(this,"You have bought the " + sku + ". Excellent choice!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = completedLevels.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("Paid", true).commit();

              }
              catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Failed to Parse data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please post more of logcat, say about 25 lines above the ones you've shown.

Comment: Use `gSon` library by Google for parsing and creating Java objects. Just saying...

Comment: in your thread `try { /* your code */ } catch (Throwable t) { Log.w("the error is", t); }`

Answer (score 0):

There are several thing in your code that could have gone wrong.

One thing that is guaranteed to crash your app:

```
Bundle skuDetails = null;

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
}
```

That's a guaranteed `NullPointerException` whenever you click. You intended that the thread assigns something to `skuDetails` already but does not:

- It uses it's own local variable: `Bundle skuDetails = mService.get..`
- Even if you would use the correct variable from within the thread it would not finish assigning a value to `skuDetails` at that point. It runs in parallel and there is no guarantee when it's done.

What you want to do here is either to do all the processing within that background thread (everything that's done in onclick after starting the thread) or to use an `AsyncTask` that reads and processes in background (`doInBackground`) then uses the processed data within the UI thread to do final steps (`onPostExecute(data returned from doInBackground)`).

There are also other problematic things. For example `mService` could still be `null` or `null` again because the service was unbound.

```
IInAppBillingService mService = null;
bindService(...); -> causes assignment to `mService` at unknown time in future.
```

There is no guarantee when mService is safe to use. Some time after the app is initialized but that could still be after user presses a button and your thread could die because of a `NullPointerException`. Check that you don't access a `null`.